# Standard practice for including compiler with installer in Windows

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, executable

Say I developed a simple software using C++, and I want to distribute it for free.  For simplicity sake assume it is some sort of GUI.  Now when I compile it on Windows and run the .exe, it works as intended.  However, the end user might have a different version of Windows then I do.  So the .exe file may not run because of differences in machine code or instruction set (I think?) In these situation is it common practice to include the compiler to the end user so that the compiler is built and then my source code is compiled or do I use a cross compiler instead? Or how is it commonly done? Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: You should not include a compiler with your source code. Just inform the user what compiler and version that the code was tested with. You could even post a link to how to download that exact compiler version.

Comment: For most applications the OS version is not the issue. Usually the dependant dll's /so's are missing. I would suggest finding the depending libraries and include them in the installer (or distribution package). On Windows there would be http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to list all (usually) dll dependencies.